# Is every uniformly continuous function 1-1 and onto?

Tags: metric-spaces, uniform-continuity

Let $f : (X,d)\rightarrow (Y,\rho)$. Is $f$ 1-1 and onto if $f$ is a uniformly continuous function on X?
If not, would $X$ being compact change things?
If not, do you know a theorem or something similar to this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, a constant function is uniformly continuous...

Comment: Continuity, and, even more, uniforme continuity, says that $Y$ is, in some sense, less chaotic than $X$. But $X$ can be arbitrarily more chaotic than $Y$. In other words: the existence of a continuous function from $X$ to $Y$ is NOT symmetric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a counterexample for both, consider a constant function when the domain and codomain both have more than one element.